# Facing an issue while installing node-inspector

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Since Yesterday I was stack due to below `npm` issue.

1. when I run `npm --version` it's returning `'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
   2.15.8`
2. When I try to run `node-inspector`, it's returning

> CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> v8-debug@0.7.7 preinstall D:\Practice\loopbackPractice\EMployeeDetails\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
>   node -e 'process.exit(0)'
>
> v8-profiler@5.6.5 preinstall D:\Practice\loopbackPractice\EMployeeDetails\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-profiler
>   node -e 'process.exit(0)'
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-inspector"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.7
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
>   npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
>   npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>   npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
>
> npm ERR! v8-debug@0.7.7 preinstall: `node -e 'process.exit(0)'`
>   npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.7.7 preinstall script 'node -e 'process.exit(0)''.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node -e 'process.exit(0)'
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs v8-debug
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\Practice\loopbackPractice\EMployeeDetails\npm-debug.log`

I have reinstalled and tried again still same kind of issue. These issues are facing after I try to install `node-gyp`

can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: Do you reboot after installing node on windows? You required to do that in order for node and npm to start working.

Comment: I did it still not working same issue.

Comment: If nothing else works then try to uninstall node and npm then make sure to remove node_modules folder in c:/Users/your-name/appdata/roaming/npm or even entire npm folder, restart, install node again

Answer (score 0):

if your system variables have '`com spec`', just delete it, then everything will be ok!